# ExtJS 2.3 Column custom renderer append boxcomponent

Tags: extjs

I would like to append a small square with a custom background color to a column based on the column value.

I define a renderer function for the column such as:

```
this.addColorSqureToToTextColumn = function(value,meta,record,rowIndex,colIndex,store) {
  var color = record.get("color");
  return value; // how to append a boxcomponent with the background color after the value?
}
```

I know I can change the meta css for the entire column and set the background color, but I would like to have a little colored square next to the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't realize you can simply return html markup:

```
this.addColorSqureToToTextColumn = function(value,meta,record,rowIndex,colIndex,store) {
  var color = record.get("color");
  return value + "<div style='position: relative; left: 10px; top: 5px;display:inline-block;height:20px;width:20px;background-color:" + color + ";'></div>";
}
```

Returning a block 20x20 appended to my value